# Error In location fetching using fusedLocationProviderClient for initial installation

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, geolocation

I am developing an android app in android studio with firebase real time Data base. App need to collect the location of the device. I don't want to have continuous location information. I need to save device longitude and latitude information in my data base.  I am encountering an interesting situation while fetching the device location using fusedLocationProviderClient. The problem is that when I first install my app in a new device location fetching takes a lot of time, some times it will not work at all or work after 3 or 4 HOURS..but once it catches the location , every thing works fine, even if I uninstall the app and re install also location is working fine, even if I clear the catches and data it will work fine,.The problem occurs only for the first installation. I am putting the code for fetching the location below, I had used geocoder for displaying the address.. Any one please check my code and please let me know whether there is any better way to do this

```
private void getCurrentLocation() {


    fusedLocationProviderClient.flushLocations();// used for refreshing (don't know correct or not)


    fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {

            Location location=task.getResult();
            //Check condition
            if(location !=null){

                BuyerLatitude=String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                BuyerLongitude=String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

                // ----------------- Geocoder is used to find the address -----------------

                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(BuyerAreaFinderActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),1);
                    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                    BuyerArea.setText(address);
                    BuyerAreaFetchBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //------------------up to here for Geocoder-------------------------------------------------------------------------------


            }
            else {
                //Location update.. when location result is null , Initialize location update part
                // LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest() //deprecated so changed by me

                LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                        .setInterval(10000)
                        .setFastestInterval(1000)
                        .setNumUpdates(1);

                //Initialize location call back

                LocationCallback locationCallback=new LocationCallback(){
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                        Location location1=locationResult.getLastLocation();

                        BuyerLatitude=String.valueOf(location1.getLatitude());
                        BuyerLongitude=String.valueOf(location1.getLongitude());
                    }
                };
                // Request location updates
                
                fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,locationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"We are collecting your location details. Please wait for few seconds and press the button again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);


            }

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: @AlexMamo I also dont know whats the problem with this code, but for initial installation it is taking too much time to collect location.. after that every thing is working fine